# Express Node.js project missing parameter in route

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple route defined such as

```
gApp.use('/alert/:product', routeAlertProduct); // example: http://localhost/alert/test
```

However, when handling the route. The request.params field is empty. When I expect it should have been filled in with a key representing the product (which should be set to test in the above example).

[image]

Any thoughts on why request.params doesn't contain a product key in this example?

Answer (score 0):

`router.get('/', . . .` doesn't have any parameters.  Take a look at the request inside it, the url will be '/'.

Routers are designed to be interchangeable by having them completely ignorant of being routed by another router.

As for a fix, you can add a middleware that notes down the param.

```
gApp.use('/alert/:product', function noteDownTheProduct (req, res, next) {
  req.product = req.params.product;
  next();
}, routeAlertProduct);
```

Not tested, but if I recall correctly it should work.